# Enterprise library 6 Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching missing?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, enterprise-library-6

I saw the ICacheManager in Enterprise libary 5 and wanted to check it out. I cant find it in Enterprise library 6.

What happened to it? Is it renamed? Is it deprecated because there are problems with it?

Answer (score 2):

Found it on

https://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib6ReleaseNotes

> ### Deprecated Blocks
>
> The following blocks have been deprecated and removed from the Enterprise Library.
>
> 1. Caching Application Block
> 2. Cryptography Application Block
> 3. Security Application Block